# Last child CSS3

Tags: css, pseudo-class, css-selectors

I need to delete the left-border from the first item and the right-border from the fourth item in a list without affecting any of the sub lists of those items. How can I do this?

My code for the menu list is:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul><li><a href="#">First Item</a><ul>
  <li><a href="#">First Sub Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second Sub Item</a></li>
  </ul></li></ul>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Second Item</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First Sub Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Sub Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Third Item</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First Sub Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Sub Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Fourth Item</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First Sub Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Sub Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

that is the code i add border with

```
#menu ul li a { padding: 10px; display: inline-block; border-right-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-right-color: #CCC; border-left-color: #000; }
```

and i used this code to delete the border from the first child

```
#menu ul:first-child a { border-left: 0px; }
```

it works perfectly but when i do the same to delete from last-child ,, it effects the sub items ul li ul li a not ul li a

i can't manually add class to last child as it comes dynamically so i don't know how many items the admin will add at the future

Comment: having some CSS for this question would allow us to figure out which element has the borders so we can help.

Comment: @user1370371 Please supply CSS and we'll be able to give and explain actual working code rather than guessing as to what migh fix the problem you're having.

Comment: @user1370371 Thank you for that but I think we need a little more, namely all CSS that makes up and affects `#menu` we need it so we can see how it looks and have a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve. You could also do this by making a screenshot and circling the borders that need to dissapear since atm, it is quite vague.

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu ul:first-child { border-left: 0; }
#menu ul:last-child { border-right: 0; }
```

Note that last-child isn't supported in IE until IE9. First-child should work in IE7 and up.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
#menu  ul li a { padding: 10px; display: inline-block; border-right-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-right-color: #CCC; border-left-color: #000; color:#000; }

#menu > ul:first-child > li > a { border-left: 0px;} 

#menu > ul:last-child > li > a { border-right: 0px}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Item:

`#menu ul:first-child`

Last Item:

`#menu ul:last-child`

For full browser compatibility, add another class to the first and last elements

```
 <ul class="first-list">
  <li><a href="#">First Item</a><ul>
  <li><a href="#">First Sub Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second Sub Item</a></li>
  </ul></li></ul>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Second Item</a>
      ...

  <ul class="last-list">
    <li><a href="#">Fourth Item</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First Sub Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Sub Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

.first-list {}
.last-list {}
```

Most languages support detectors for first and last entries in queries or arrays.

**OR**

If you're using jquery, you can select like so:

`$('#menu ul:first').addClass('first-list')`